# Ban a user if they leave the server when they have a specific role discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want make it so if a user leaves the server while they have the `Muted` or `[Banned]` role they get permanently banned.

This is the code that I tried:

```
@bot.event
async def on_member_remove(ctx, member, reason=None):
    role="[Banned]"
    guild = ctx.guild
    if role in member.roles:
        await guild.ban(discord.Object(id=member.id), reason="Leaved the server when soft banned")
```

*this is just a try with only the banned role.

The user doesn't get banned, there is also no error or anything that could help me troubleshoot it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[member.roles](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=on_member_remove#discord.on_member_remove) returns a List of [Role](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=roles#discord.Role)

You need to get the Role object which one way you can use is:

```
role = discord.utils.find(lambda r: r.name == '[Banned]', member.guild.roles)
```

[on_member_remove](http://on_member_remove) takes in Member. You cannot have `reason` or Context(`ctx`)

```py
@bot.event
async def on_member_remove(member):
    role = discord.utils.find(lambda r: r.name == '[Banned]', member.guild.roles)
    guild = member.guild
    if role in member.roles:
        await guild.ban(discord.Object(id=member.id), reason="Leaved the server when soft banned")
```

Please also ensure you have the Members intent enabled. You can do this by going [here](https://discord.com/developers/applications) then selecting `Bot` -> SERVER MEMBERS INTENT

You will need to do enable intents in your code by using:

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=".", intents=intents)
```

Answer (score -1):

Check that you have enabled the `Intents.members` on your Discord Developper portal and in your bot code, if you're using Discord API v8 (as intents are mandatory in this API version), as explained [here in Discord.py docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.on_member_remove).

For your information, by default, all intents are enabled except `members` and `presence` intents.

On Discord Developer Portal, enable this in the "Bot" section of your app : [image]

**Edit : Discord Intents have now changed again and there are more and more checks performed by Discord. Check the Discord documentation : https://discord.com/developers/docs/**