# Discord.py | How to assign someone a role?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I am trying to mute someone using a role `Muted`
The Code:

```
@bot.command()
async def mute(ctx, member:commands.MemberConverter):
    role = discord.utils.find(lambda r: r.name == 'Muted', ctx.guild.roles)
    await member.edit(roles=[role])
```

But I get this weird error:

```
Ignoring exception in command mute:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\gathi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\gathi\Vscode\Discord_Bot\tutorial.py", line 61, in mute
    await member.edit(roles=[role]) # 848410518154117130
  File "C:\Users\gathi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\member.py", line 681, in edit
    await http.edit_member(guild_id, self.id, reason=reason, **payload)
  File "C:\Users\gathi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 248, in request
    raise Forbidden(r, data)
discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\gathi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\gathi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\gathi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions
```

I don't understand what to do.

Here is the perms of the bot:
[The bots perms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lroXO.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is within the bot `Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions` should instantly tell you it's a permissions issue.

The bot fails on `await member.edit(roles=[role]) # 848410518154117130` which tells you the code works but it can't assign the role.

Make sure the bot:

- Is higher than you in the role hierarchy
- Has `Manage Roles` or the `Administrator` permission

If this continues to not work then consider going to my previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67658738/ban-a-user-if-they-leave-the-server-when-they-have-a-specific-role-discord-py/67659021#67659021) about intents.

Comment: I did check that, but I'll do so again

Answer (score -1):

You can use `discord.Member.add_roles` to assign a role.

```
@bot.command()
async def mute(ctx, member: commands.MemberConverter):
    role = discord.utils.find(lambda r: r.name == 'Muted', ctx.guild.roles)
    await member.add_roles(role)
```

And this is the `unmute` command.

```
@bot.command()
async def unmute(ctx, member: commands.MemberConverter):
    role = discord.utils.find(lambda r: r.name == 'Muted', ctx.guild.roles)
    await member.remove_roles(role)
```